# Finding a basis for a subset $\mathbb{R}^4$ for which $x_2 = x_3$ holds

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to find a basis for which $\mathbb{R}^4$ for which $x_2 = x_3$ holds. I'm not quite sure how to think about this. For some reason, the solution is taking the basis of the null space (so the free variables of the solution of $Ax = 0$)? Why is it the basis of the null space exactly, and not say, the basis of the column space?

Would appreciate some help understanding these, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean "a basis of the subspace $\{(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) \in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid x_2 = x_3\}$". If this is the case, the standard procedure is as follows:

A general element of this subspace is $(x_1, x_2, x_2, x_4)$. But this can be decomposed as a linear combination $x_1(1, 0, 0, 0) + x_2(0, 1, 1, 0) + x_4(0, 0, 0, 1)$. Therefore, the set $B = \{(1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1)\}$ generates the aforementioned subspace. Now all you have to do is to prove they are linear independent.

But I ask you to please be more specific in your question, as I don't quite understand what null/column spaces you are talking about, or what your question really is...

Comment: Hey Gauss, do you mind explaining why you have $x_2$ up there instead of $x_3$? Since $x_2$ is a pivot column, I would think it's $x_1(1,0,0,0) + x_3(0,-1,1,0) + x_4(0,0,0,1)$

Comment: @JakeDrone It doesn’t matter, because they are equal. They are just parameters: you can call them “potato” and it wouldn’t change the result :)

Comment: But the values are different? $x_3 = (0,-1,1,0)$ and your $x_2$ is $(0,1,1,0)$.. and $x_2$ is a pivot column..?

Comment: @JakeDrone $x_i$ are not vectors, they are real numbers